# NLSSORT Oracle to Snowflake

Tags: sql, oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql, nls-sort

I'm trying to convert the following code from Oracle to Snowflake:

`order by nlssort(name, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY')`

I know NLSSORT is not a function in Snowflake, but is there anything I can use as an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be pretty similar already to Snowflake's default sorting - you just need to consider your database charset in Oracle (`select * from nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET'`) and see whether it has a different binary order than ASCII/UTF-8.

[Oracle's documentation:](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-04243CDA-43CA-4AF8-B59D-6FB841B307BE.htm#REFRN10127)

> If the value is BINARY, then comparison is based directly on byte
> values in the binary encoding of the character values being compared.

[Snowflake's documentation:](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/order-by.html)

> All data is sorted according to the numeric byte value of each
> character in the ASCII table. UTF-8 encoding is supported.

So I think you should be able to just do:

```
order by name
```

It's kind of odd that somebody would write that Oracle code to begin with, since BINARY is the default sort order (collation). But if your Oracle database is [using multilingual collation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/nlspg/linguistic-sorting-and-matching.html) (which is not common) for other queries, I don't think you're going to be able to easily emulate that in Snowflake.